# Summing a column in SSRS which contains duplicate values

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi

I am trying to sum a column in SSRS with duplicate values and have been unable to avoid having all values be included in the sum total.  I am trying to set up a table of financial accounts.  The main Report list will be filtered by households. Households consist of multiple accounts.  The table will be a table of accounts. When attempting to total the column called 'Total_account_value' the SUM includes every value not just the unique ones.

[image]

I have tried to sum max values and several other  expressions but have not had success.

Comment: show us a smple of your dataset and what you are trying to sum from that dataset

Comment: If you fix it in the dataset, the report will just display the data. Change your query to return exactly what you want to display. Try the windows functions in SQL for ranking.